# SharpDX and setting one color as transparent (directx9)

Tags: c#, bitmap, directx, sharpdx

I have a C# capture application that captures screenshot of an application and draws it to another window. Now I would like to set one color (or range) of the screenshot to be transparent and then draw it like that.

I am drawing the screenshot as sprite to 3d (directx9) surface using SharpDX.

How can I do this transparency?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When converting your screenshot to a texture, your colors should be defined by four values R,G,B,A. Alpha channel is responsible for transparency, so you should check if a color has a value / range that you want to cut out and change it's alpha value to 0.

Answer (score 0):

It was a bit odd situation. My alpha modified pictures did not show up when draw:ing.
It was because I did not specify alphablend mode in .Begin-statement.
And I did not find any other way to do it than going through the whole bitmap and changing the alpha value one pixel at the time.